# Keep duplicates with a condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
data = [['p1', 0, 'dog'], ['p2', 0, 'dog'], ['p5', 1, 'dog'], ['p6', 1, 'cat'], ['p7', 1, 'dog'], ['p8', 2, 'cat'],['p3', 2, 'cat'], ['p4', 2, 'cat'],  ['p12', 3, 'cat'], 
       ['p9', 3, 'cat'], ['p10', 3, 'dog'], ['p11', 3, 'dog'], ['p13', 4, 'cat']]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = ['id', 'rank', 'group'])
sdf.show()
+---+----+-----+
| id|rank|group|
+---+----+-----+
| p1|   0|  dog|
| p2|   0|  dog|
| p5|   1|  dog|
| p6|   1|  cat|
| p7|   1|  dog|
| p8|   2|  cat|
| p3|   2|  cat|
| p4|   2|  cat|
|p12|   3|  cat|
| p9|   3|  cat|
|p10|   3|  dog|
|p11|   3|  dog|
|p13|   4|  cat|
+---+----+-----+
```

I have duplicates on the rank column and on the group column.I want to remove the rows where for the rank **all `group column` are the same completely**. If there is still a difference (even with a duplicate) in `group` column for `rank`, then this should be left

In the end, the final dataframe will be

```
 +---+----+-----+
| id|rank|group|
+---+----+-----+
| p5|   1|  dog|
| p6|   1|  cat|
| p7|   1|  dog|
|p12|   3|  cat|
| p9|   3|  cat|
|p10|   3|  dog|
|p11|   3|  dog|
|p13|   4|  cat|
+---+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another dataframe and apply your criteria on it, then join it back to the first dataframe on the rank column to keep only the desired ones:

```
tmpDf = sdf.groupby("rank").agg(countDistinct("group").alias("group"), count("rank").alias("count")) \
    .filter((col("group") > 1) | (col("count") == 1)).select("rank")
result = tmpDf.join(sdf, ["rank"], "left")
result.show()

+----+---+-----+
|rank| id|group|
+----+---+-----+
|   1| p7|  dog|
|   1| p6|  cat|
|   1| p5|  dog|
|   3|p11|  dog|
|   3|p10|  dog|
|   3| p9|  cat|
|   3|p12|  cat|
|   4|p13|  cat|
+----+---+-----+
```